# OpenSAML and RelayState

Tags: saml, opensaml

I had a look around the forum here and read a few threads, but I don't think there is an answer to my question. Having said that, I am by no means a SAML expert so some of the threads I read I did so with glossy eyes :).

I have inherited some code that uses OpenSAML (on the SP side) to generate a request and send it over to an ADFS implementation. The issue I am looking into is the fact that the user is always returned to the same url, regardless of an initial request for say a deeplink into the site. Now, on the ADFS side I know that that redirect back to the SP is static which won't help, but I am 99.9% sure that we are not passing any redirection values to the provider. From my research, I think I should be using the RelayState to pass the value so that it is echo'ed back to me, so that I can use it after processing the SAML Response.

My problem is that I am not clear on how to pass the RelayState in the first place. In the code I am working with I can see a class defined --

```
public class HTTPRedirectTransportSender extends HTTPServletTransportSender
{
    private static final transient Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HTTPRedirectTransportSender.class);

    public HTTPRedirectTransportSender(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
    {
        super(httpServletResponse);
    }


    @Override
    protected BaseHttpServletResponseXMLMessageEncoder buildMessageEncoder()
    {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder();
    }

}
```

.. and if I look at the HttpRedirectDeflateDecoder then I can see some logic about building the url and such. I've been searching for a while now but I haven't found an example that I am sure will be what I am looking for -- so I was hoping an expert out there might be able to help?

Comment: perhaps this might help. I've just answered a similar question but for javascript. I have a JSP with SAMLRequest and RelayState that gets POSTed automatically but it should let you see how to send RelayState https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700273/saml2-submitting-xml-samlrequest-value-in-a-form/48701900#48701900

Comment: Just to make clear what you're asking  your site (the SP) causes the client's browser to issue a request to a ADFS (a GET request)? And now you're wondering how to attach the RelayState to this request?

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely thinking about it right. You'll want to save the user's originally entered URL and use it as the relay state.

For OpenSAML v3, you attach the relay state to the `MessageContext`. You'll have to find where your application is building the `MessageContext` and do something like this:

```java
SAMLBindingSupport.setRelayState(messageContext, relayState);
```

This is a convenience method provided by the OpenSAML library; in the background, it's accessing the `SAMLBindingContext` subcontext from your `MessageContext` (creating it if necessary) and setting the relay state on that.

```java
messageContext.getSubcontext(SAMLBindingContext.class, true).setRelayState(relayState);
```

Answer (score 0):

RelayState is typically used for IDPInitiated as per [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/09/27/ad-fs-2-0-relaystate/).

As per [this](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/11/adfs-relaystate-with-idpinitiated.html), "Don't be confused by the fact that RelayState serves two completely separate purposes. For IdPInitiated, the RelayState specifies the landing page at the SP. For SPInitiated it's a way for the SP to maintain state information between sending the AuthnRequest and receiving the SAML response. RelayState may be sent along with the AuthnRequest and the IDP must return this RelayState along with the SAML response."

Comment: Sure, but, as you stated in the paragraph it is also often used by the SP to save some state -- like the URL that was requested before the auth process started. If someone deep links into the site http://www.somesite.com/this/is/a/protected/url ... and is then redirected to the IdP, who then returns the user to the http://www.somesite.com/saml/auth to process the response, then I could  use the relay state in a success scenario to redirect the user to the original URL. My question was not so much what the relay state is, but rather HOW to pass it to the IdP.

Comment: As above - put in AuthnRequest.