# SAML2 Submitting XML SAMLRequest value in a form

Tags: javascript, xml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to authenticate user logon with `SAML`. I have a simple `HTML` form.

```
<form method="post" action="https://abcd/login"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="request" /> 
   <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="token" /> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

I'm confused about how I can send the `base64` encoding of the `XML` for the `SAMLRequest` with just `javascript`. It would be a huge help if someone could point me in the right direction or link to a demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what SAML2 profile you are using. Assuming you're using Web Browser SSO (WBSSO) it's all done via automatically sending the browser to URLs via POSTing. The user accesses your application and you create the SAMLRequest and RelayState and automatically POST the form to the IdP. The IdP authenticates the user (you don't care about this part) and then automatically redirects the browser back to your Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) URL with a base64 SAMLReponse containing the authentication information and attributes. There's a simple overview of the SP initiated process [here](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml).

Here's how I do it:

```
<html>
  <body Onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form method="POST" action="<%= request.getAttribute("wbsso_endpoint") %>">
      <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="<%= request.getAttribute("SAMLRequest") %>">
      <% if (request.getAttribute("RelayState") != null) { %>
        <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="<%= request.getAttribute("RelayState") %>">
      <% } %>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```